# Making an embed that takes an awaited response from a user and separates it into four words

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I don't know how to get it to separate the words so it displays one word per line on an embed.
Under .setDescription, I'm using the first 6 characters of the content since this "word" should always be 6 characters. However, the rest could be a variety of characters, so I can't be specific. I figure I could use the split by space again, but I can't figure out how to use that in the code to display it properly.

```js
if (collected.first().content.split(" ").length === 4) {
    var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setDescription(collected.first().content.slice(0, 6) + "\n \n(If there is a checkmark reaction at the bottom by the host, the game lobby is full.)")
        .setTimestamp(new Date())
        .setColor("0x7346EE");

    DChannel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: If you split a string it turns it into an array, just indent every element of said array

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I would say the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for is with [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). You can then make each word a new line with [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
const message = 'Hello World! What a Beautiful Day.'; // example message
const words = message.split(/ +/); // split by every space(s)
console.log(words.join('\n')); // join each element by a line break
```